# Get current SharePoint file version using REST call

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest, file-metadata

I use a REST call to get file information as:

`http://MY_WEB_SITE/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Documents')/items?$select=FileLeafRef`

Can I get the current file version using same REST call? If so how ?

This didn't workout
`http://MY_WEB_SITE/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Documents')/items?$select=FileLeafRef,_UIVersionString`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the RESTful URL you need to get the current file version of a specific file (by its ID):

```
http://MY_WEB_SITE/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Documents')/items(1)?$select=FileLeafRef,OData__UIVersionString
```

Here is the RESTful URL you need to get the current file version for all files in the library:

```
http://MY_WEB_SITE/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Documents')/items?$select=FileLeafRef,OData__UIVersionString
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the specific file's version using REST call by below given code.

```
// Get the file versions
    function getFileVersions() {
        var getfileurl = document.getElementById("getfileurl").value;
        var executor;
        // Initialize the RequestExecutor with the app web URL.
        executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
        executor.executeAsync({
            url: appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('" + getfileurl + "')/Versions?@target='" + hostweburl + "'",
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
            },
            success: getFileVersionsSuccessHandler,
            error: getFileVersionsErrorHandler
        });
    }

    // Success Handler
    function getFileVersionsSuccessHandler(data) {
        var versions = 'File Versions:\n'
        var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data.body);
        var results = jsonObject.d.results;
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            versions += results[i].VersionLabel + '\n';
        }
        // Display the File versions
        alert(versions);
    }

    // Error Handler
    function getFileVersionsErrorHandler(data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
        alert("Could not get the file versions: " + errorMessage);
    }
```

**Note:-** Kindly change the variable values as per your environment.