# Get file of specific version using JSOM in share point 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jsom, version-history

I want to get the file of specific previous versions using java script object model in SharePoint 2013 environment.

Please share the code if any one is already worked on similar requirement.

Thanks,

Kailash

Comment: Do you wan the solution using JSOM only? Or you can also use SharePoint REST api?

Answer (score 0):

**Using JSOM**:

You can use the below sample code that uses the `restoreByLabel` method to restore the previous version of the document:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function() {
       SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext',restoreFile);
    });

    var oFile;
    function restoreFile() {
        //Get client context and web
        clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
        var oWeb = clientContext.get_web();
        //Get File object and restore a specific version
        oFile=oWeb.getFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/Playground/Demo
         Library/Document.docx');
        oFile.get_versions().restoreByLabel("6.0");

        //Load Client Context and execute the batch
        clientContext.load(oFile);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(QuerySuccess, QueryFailure);
    }
    function QuerySuccess() {
        //Get major version
        var majorVersion =oFile.get_majorVersion();
       console.log("Version Restored . New Major Version - "+ majorVersion );
    } 

    function QueryFailure(sender,args) {
       console.log('Request failed - '+args.get_message());
    }
</script>
```

**Using REST API**:

You can use below endpoint to get all version of file:

```
siteUrl/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('fileURL')/Versions
```

[Get current SharePoint file version using REST call](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/183993/get-current-sharepoint-file-version-using-rest-call)

Comment: Thanks for the code Ganesh. My concern is I want the file object which is itself a previous version document object and going forward I will consume that file object and upload the same in some other library.

Here in the code you are trying to restore the previous version.

Comment: Can anyone please suggest the way to get the specific version file?